# Casting to an indirect subclass

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I have been playing around with the google drive api and am having a hard time understanding why I cannot cast `Result` to `DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult`.  In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/Result.html) `DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult` is a indirect known subclass of `Result`, but when I try casting `Result` to `DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult` I get the exception,

```
`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.drive.internal.v$e cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi$DriveIdResult`
```

Why is this happening?  Since `DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult` is a indirect known subclass shouldn't I be able to cast it to 'Result'?

Also to help you guys I pasted some code down below. This is taken directly from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/folders). Why would this code work? How can I implement the interface `ResultCallback` to give me back `DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult`?  The best solution for me would be to have a class implement `ResultCallback`, have the method `onResult` return some object that has the method `getStatus()` and I then can cast it to any indirect subclass I want.  Is this possible?

```
ResultCallback<DriveFolderResult> folderCreatedCallback = new
                ResultCallback<DriveFolderResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveFolderResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    showMessage("Error while trying to create the folder");
                    return;
                }
                showMessage("Created a folder: " + result.getDriveFolder().getDriveId());
            }
        }
```

Also here is my class that my IDE tells me that `onResult(R)` is never being declared, but I have the method in the class.  Why is this happening?  Why can the above example return `DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult` and my class cannot?

```
public class CustomDriveResultCallback implements ResultCallback {

    private final ICustomCallback _customCallback;
    private final CustomCallbackId _customCallbackId;

    public CustomDriveResultCallback(ICustomCallback customCallback, CustomCallbackId customCallbackId){
        _customCallback = customCallback;
        _customCallbackId = customCallbackId;
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to resolve the issue and callsback to the driveCallbackHandler if it fails or throws an exception
     * https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes.html
     * @param result
     */
    public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult result) {
        if(result.getStatus().isSuccess()){
            _customCallback.successCustomCallback(_customCallbackId, result);
        }else{
            _customCallback.failedCustomCallback(_customCallbackId, result);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only cast to a subclass if the object in question actually is an instance of that subclass or lower in the inheritance tree.

For example, let's say you have the following classes:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}
```

If you have a reference of type A which is actually an instance of B, you can cast it to B, but not to C.

Equally, if you had:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
```

You can still cast your reference of type A to a reference of type B if the object actually is an instance of B, but you cannot cast it to C. This is probably what you are trying to do.

See this similar question: [Typical Hierarchical inheritance in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337759/typical-hierarchical-inheritance-in-java)

Comment: Okay, but why does the above example ResultCallback<DriveFolderResult> folderCreatedCallback work and my class CustomDriveResultCallback complain about the method signature being wrong?

Comment: In the error, Java is telling you that the real instance is actually a `com.google.android.gms.drive.internal.v$e`. This class does not extend `DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult` (because if it did, then you would not have seen the error). That is why you can't cast it.

Comment: In the docs it say that DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult implements Result.
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult.html

Comment: But that's not your main problem, which is that you cannot cast from `com.google.android.gms.drive.internal.v$e` to `DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult` because the first class does not extend the second.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `ResultCallback` is a [generic class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) - that's why you see `ResultCallback<DriveFolderResult>` in your first code sample and not just `ResultCallback`. You need to change your code so that you implement `ResultCallback<DriveFolderResult>`.